# Importing numpy in python take an error

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I try to run import numpy on my machine. but after do it take an error like this:

```
$ python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

The error is about numpy! i try to check numpy by excute this command

```
$apt-cache policy python-numpy
python-numpy:
  Installed: 1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

this show that numpy install in my machine in correct state.
i uninstalled numpy and all of my python dependency in my machine and install it again.
but problem is exist. i cant find what is the problem?

Comment: my $PYTHONPATH is value /usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: have you tried to reinstall?

Comment: Yes. I uninstall all package and install it again. But error exist.!

Comment: Try to install it using `pip`.